# Limit active dimensions for vrp problem in ortools

Tags: or-tools

Suppose one wants that a vehicle can move different items, e.g. watermelons and chlorine. Both types of items can be assigned to a vehicle, but only one at a time. So the vehicle can only transport either watermelons or chlorine, but not both simultaneously. Now, I know one can create different `dimensions` for putting capacity constraints for both types of items, but how do we enforce that only one dimension is active at any time ?

I thought of hacking it in a way where each category is label encoded to a number and putting an upper bound on that (e.g. watermelon = 1 and chlorine =2), but that wouldn't work. Any suggestions in how to approach this ?

Comment: I am thinking, is this doable via [resource constraints](https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/cvrptw_resources#vrptw-example-with-resource-constraints) ?

Comment: As far as I am aware of or-tools doesn't support such restrictions. However, it does support [node restrictions](https://github.com/google/or-tools/issues/334#issuecomment-484781754). Using that example one can restriction which vehicles can visit which nodes based on pre-defined constraints.